# lazy-loading doubleclick ads versus enableSingleRequest()

Tags: jquery, google-dfp

In an attempt to increase Active In-View metrics, I'm trying to defer a display ad call (`googletag.display('ad-' + adLocation)`) by wrapping it in an 'in-view' check (using jquery.inview), but this only seems to work if I disable `googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();` Am I correct in understanding that `enableSingleRequest()` is overriding my calls to `googletag.display`?

To clarify, `enableSingleRequest` is necessary in order for us to serve guaranteed roadblocks, but we also need to ensure that ads are only being served when they are in-view.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Answer:**

Google Ad Manager (how DFP is now named) now [provides a configurable LazyLoad parameter](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_enableLazyLoad) which can be used with enableSingleRequest().

**Old Answer:**

At face value, no.

What you could do is render different blocks of ads with different Single Requests, so you render your road-blocked slots together, and other ads at other times.

The problem is that, as far as I know, DFP resets the correlator every 30 seconds, so if you don't use Single Requests, you risk losing your roadblocks, which depend on the correlator to know they're part of the same request.

Another tactic you could try is to wait 25 seconds or so to render your below-the-fold ads; they would still be rendered within Same Correlator Time, ensuring a roadblock, but if the user closes the window before that, the ad doesn't render, increasing your viewability ratio. But I haven't tried that myself (I'm currently researching this very issue...)

Answer (score 3):

I realize this may be a few years too late, but I work for a company that was dealing with this problem. We needed to increase viewability metrics, but couldn't find a supported solution that would allow us to lazy load ads while respecting the SRA competitive roadblocks. We eventually came up with a solution that uses the 30 changeCorrelator timeout. It's been running in production for almost a year and we're pretty happy with it, I published a gist here: https://gist.github.com/davewalker235/e090c19cef62206b14a0fe2677168515.

That having been said, Google just published an update to the platform allowing the changeCorrelator to last indefinitely. So we may be updating this soon to get rid of the 30 second setTimeout code that forces all ads to load before the 30 second correlator times out. The release notes are here: https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/179039?hl=en

Comment: I just posted a comment on the gist and then I found it was linked from this answer. So in case you see this first...I just wanted to mention that the `support.google.com` link just points to the latest release notes. Do you have a more specific link? Thank you

Comment: Ah, yup, their release notes don't have permanent links. Here's a link to the 2018 release notes: https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7636572. You can find the one I was referring too under the October 29th section. They  refer to the feature as "Long-lived page views".